# Print to pdf settings - using RestFul Api - SAP Business Object / .Net

Tags: .net, rest, pdf, business-objects

I would like to create a functionality in my Application to generate the reports as pdf from SAP Business Objects (WebI / Web Intelligence) using [RESTFul API](https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US).

Everything works fine, except the thing that the pdf doesn't have any margins etc. (so every page is different). Of course when I generate the report from BO (save as pdf or generate as pdf), I have proper settings - (those in Page Setup in BO).

Could you please advise what can be the problem?
Thank you

Comment: You need to provide some code.  It is very difficult to help you if we cannot see what you are doing.

Comment: Hello, can you add the REST call you are using so that I can analyze this behavior on our internal reports ? Thanks, Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick look at the [documentation](https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/45f8c7de6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html).
I guess you are using the following call to export the document as PDF:

`<base_webi_REST_URL>/documents/8022/pages?mode=quickDisplay"`

You should update the export mode, if you want to have the same size for each page of the document.

`<base_webi_REST_URL>/documents/8022/pages?mode=normal"`

The `normal` mode is corresponding to a Print mode where all pages of the document are exported with the size options configured into Web Intelligence.

The `quickDisplay` mode is generally used in browser and the page size is calculated in function of the data displayed on the page (in this case, the pages are calculated in function of a maximum number of rows and columns) - this is the reason why your are seeing different page sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much it works:) i was trying with mode=normal, however i forgot to add "pages". So my url was reportid?mode=normal. And thanks for confirming that by default it is quickDisplay. (Url was used not in paginated mode )